# Mondrian Rollup Total with a dimension

Tags: pentaho, olap, mondrian

I want mondrian to rollup as per my dimension table. For example

fact_table(id int, dim_id)

- 1 2
- 2 2
- 3 1
- 4 3

dimension_table( dim_id, value)

- 1 first_value
- 2 second_value

The last value in fact_table is delibrately not in the list of dimensions

```
<Cube name="BYT">
         <Dimension type="StandardDimension" visible="true" 
                   highCardinality="false" name="d1">
    <Hierarchy name="dimension_table" visible="true" hasAll="true">
      <Table name="dimension_table">
      </Table>
      <Level name="dimension" visible="true" column="dim_id" 
            type="String" uniqueMembers="false" levelType="Regular" 
                  hideMemberIf="Never">
      </Level>
    </Hierarchy>
  </Dimension>
     <Measure name="m1"  column="id"  datatype="Integer" 
           aggregator="count" visible="true">
    </Measure>
    <Cube>
```

when i fire the following query

```
select [Measure].[m1] on columns, {([d1])} on rows from [BYT]
```

The result is

```
 - Dimension  Measure
 - All D1     4
```

What i would like mondrian to do is something like this

```
- Dimension  Measure
- All D1     3
```

i.e. count only on the values included in the dimension table

Please suggest a solution. I read through the rollup policy in the documentation but that does not help my case.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you well, there is mistake in your cube xml.
You should put `distinct count` instead of `count`.

```
<Measure name="m1"  column="id"  datatype="Integer" 
       aggregator="distinct count" visible="true">
</Measure>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a NON EMPTY context, which will result in a join with your fact table.

```
select [Measure].[m1] on columns, NON EMPTY {([d1])} on rows from [BYT]
```